# Axiomatic explanation of why the volume of a parallelepiped is equal to the area of its base times its height

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, measure-theory

I asked this in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331787/axiomatic-explanation-of-why-the-volume-of-a-parallelepiped-is-equal-to-the-area?noredirect=1#comment2706068_1331787), it flashed and disappeared.

Let $V_n$ be the volume on the set of polytopes in $\mathbb R^n$, *defined axiomatically*, i.e. a functional, that assigns to each polytope $P\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ a real number $V_n(P)\ge 0$ in such a way that the following conditions are fulfilled:

1. For the unit hypercube $C\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ 
   $$
   V_n(C)=1,
   $$
2. If $P\cap Q=\varnothing$, then 
   $$
   V_n(P\cup Q)=V_n(P)+V_n(Q),
   $$
3. If $P$ is made from $Q$ by a *motion*, then
   $$
   V_n(P)=V_n(Q).
   $$
   Question:

   > Is there a simple way to prove that the $n$-th volume of a parallelepiped $P_{a_1,...,a_n}$ spanned by $n$ vectors $a_1,...,a_n$ is the poduct of the $n-1$-th volume of $P_{a_1,...,a_{n-1}}$ and the height of $P_{a_1,...,a_n}$ with respect to the base $P_{a_1,...,a_{n-1}}$,
   >   $$
   > V_n(P_{a_1,...,a_n})=V_{n-1}(P_{a_1,...,a_{n-1}})\cdot \left|\text{pr}_{\{a_1,...,a_{n-1}\}^\perp}(a_n)\right|
   > $$
   >   ?

(Here $\text{pr}_{\{a_1,...,a_{n-1}\}^\perp}(a_n)$ is the orthogonal projection of $a_n$ to the orthogonal complement $\{a_1,...,a_{n-1}\}^\perp$ of $\{a_1,...,a_{n-1}\}$, i.e. the height of $P_{a_1,...,a_n}$.)

P.S. This is not for math reasearch, this is for teaching.

Comment: What does `flashed and disappeared` mean... ?

Comment: Perhaps, this is my bad English. What is it called when something appears and disappears immediately?

Comment: Well, that's indeed what I thought you meant, but my confusion is that your math.SE question is still visible to me. (If you felt it didn't get enough attention on math.SE, editing-to-bump or a bounty are the standard approaches.)

Comment: I meant, disappeared from the list of the questions on the main page. I thought, this means that nobody is interested.

Comment: It seems like this should be straightforward by breaking the parallelopipeds into tiny congruent pieces and then using these pieces to approximately tile each other.

Comment: Eric, I don't understand. Do you mean that for proving this it is nesessary to extend $V_n$ to the Jordan (or Lebesgue) measure (and only after that this becomes evident)? I believe there is a simple trick that allows to prove this without going to Jordan.

Comment: You don't need the entire machinery of Jordan measure; for parallelopipeds, it is easy to directly estimate how many cubes of side length $\epsilon$ you can fit inside it.  By induction, you can approximately tile the base, and now just stack translated copies of that tiling vertically.

Comment: Is it possible that this wasn't proved in textbooks?

Comment: Alternatively (and probably more along the lines you were looking for), you can just imitate the elementary school proof that the area of a parallelogram is its base times its height (by chopping off a triangle and gluing it back on to get a rectangle).

Comment: Even for the dimension $n=3$ this trick becomes bulky. To say nothing about $n>3$. Or I don't know something? Anyway this looks like a new invention of bicycle. It's difficult to believe that nobody did this before.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your 2nd axiom by the more natural one, namely  the *inclusion-exclusion principle*,

$$\mu(P\cup Q)=\mu(P)+\mu(Q)-\mu(P\cap Q), $$

then a lot can be said.   (Functions on the set of polytopes satisfying the above conditions are called *valuations*.) I will assume this holds the sequel.

$\newcommand{\Pix}{Pix}$ Denote by $\Pix(n)$ the  set of *pixelations* of $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\bR^n$, i.e., sets that are unions of  paralelipipeds with faces parallel to the coordinate face.

Theorem 2.19  from these [very nice notes](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/val-simple.pdf) imply that for any box $B=[a_1,b_1]\times \cdots \times [a_n,b_n]$  we have

$$\mu(B)=\prod_k(b_k-a_k). $$

If you replace the nonnegativity assumption with a stronger continuity  assumption, then the  result is a special case of Hadwiger's characterization theorem; see Chapter 4 of [the same notes](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/val-simple.pdf).

Comment: Aren't the two axioms equivalent? One can extend (2) to three disjoint sets and then apply it to $P\cap Q$, $P\setminus Q$ and $Q\setminus P$

Comment: Federico, as far as I understand, the problem with the equivalence of these two axioms arises when we define polytopes as compact sets (spanned by... etc), then $P\setminus Q$ needs not to be a polytope, and the functional $V_n$ is not defined on $P\setminus Q$.